# DB2 Parallel Insert

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I have something like this to insert via application into DB2 LUW,

```
insert into MY_TABLE (CREATION_DATE, MESSAGE, IDENTIFIER) values 
(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '0', '1b0d7cfb-66ee-4372-913b-2283c6e3f0b5')
,(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '1', '1b0d7cfb-66ee-4372-913b-2283c6e3f0b6')
```

I have also some triggers installed which makes some consistency checks on the inserted row and which takes some time for execution.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  
BEFORE INSERT ON MY_TABLE
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
    FOR EACH ROW
        --some checks takes approx. 10s
        END
```

So how can I achieve that the triggers are executed parallel, do not like to wait for 20s.

Comment: IF your trigger(s) are taking 10 seconds per row then they are unfit for purpose, so sort out that problem first.

Comment: Yes will do that, but is it a way to insert parallel such like scenario. I thought, I will optimize it to 1s.

Comment: parallel inserts require multiple connections (either each in a separate thread, or a separate process).  Triggers will always frustrate insert-performance so are a poor design choice for high performance applications.

Comment: When creating a separate thread for each insert, I have to ensure that no commit will be made until all the inserts are running correctly. So do you have a sample code how to handle this with Hibernate or another ORM mapper?

Comment: What ORM mapper are you using? Does that produce the INSERT with multiple values? What types of checks are you performing (currently in the trigger)?

Comment: I am using Hibernate. In the triggers, I am making checks on date validation, mostly complex, complex consistency checks.